# Como hacer que select2 no quede mostrando ninguna opción cuando se despliega

Tags: php, jquery, select2

Estoy usando select2 para mostrar una lista de ciudades. El problema es que no encuentro la forma de que cuando se carga la página, este objeto no muestre la primera ciudad en forma predeterminada, sino que muestre el placeholder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado en la documentación, pero no logro dar con la forma de que cuando se carga la página, este objeto no muestre un elemento por defecto y sólo muestre el placeholder.

```
//Initialize Select2 Elements
$('#tipocompra').select2({
    placeholder: 'Selecciona tu ciudad'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://select2.org/placeholders), debes de asegurarte de que tengas un `<option>` vacío como primer elemento en el `<select>` para que el placeholder pueda mostrarse.

> **For single selects only**, in order for the placeholder value to appear, you must have a blank `<option>` as the first option in your `<select>` control. This is because the browser tries to select the first option by default. If your first option were non-empty, the browser would display this instead of the placeholder.

```js
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});

$(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a state",
    allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control" name="state">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Estimado @ricardo-doc , tu respuesta resolvió el problema. Te agradezco mucho tu aporte, muchas gracias.